# Extracting frames from GIF

Tags: macos, applescript, frame, extract, gif

I am trying to use Applescript or Terminal (or terminal via applescript using the do shell script command) to automatically extract the frames from a selected .gif file. I know how to do the click and drag method using Preview.app, but is there a way to do this automatically?

Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **AppKit** framework to extract frames from GIF.

Here is the AppleScript (Tested on Mavericks):

```
set gifFiles to choose file of type "com.compuserve.gif" with prompt "Select GIF's files" with multiple selections allowed
set dest to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Select the folder to save gif's frames")

set pScript to quoted form of "from AppKit import NSApplication, NSImage, NSImageCurrentFrame, NSGIFFileType; import sys, os
tName=os.path.basename(sys.argv[1])
dir=sys.argv[2]
app=NSApplication.sharedApplication() 
img=NSImage.alloc().initWithContentsOfFile_(sys.argv[1])
if img:
     gifRep=img.representations()[0]
     frames=gifRep.valueForProperty_('NSImageFrameCount')
     if frames:
         for i in range(frames.intValue()):
             gifRep.setProperty_withValue_(NSImageCurrentFrame, i)
             gifRep.representationUsingType_properties_(NSGIFFileType, None).writeToFile_atomically_(dir + tName + ' ' + str(i + 1).zfill(2) + '.gif', True)
         print (i + 1)"

repeat with f in gifFiles
    set numberOfExtractedGIFs to (do shell script "/usr/bin/python -c " & pScript & " " & (quoted form of POSIX path of f) & " " & dest) as integer
end repeat
```

This script show two dialog window, a dialog to choose GIF files, a dialog to choose the destination folder.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have one final question before my app is completed. How do I set a variable that represents the number of extracted GIFs (essentially building off of that command)?

Comment: See the updated answer, I append `print (i + 1)` to the pScript

Comment: This is awesome. Excellent answer! Just wanted to point out that you can replace NSGIFFileType with NSPNGFileType or NSJPEGFileType to get the exported files in other formats.

Comment: Actually, if you replace NSGIFFileType with NSPNGFileType in that script, it emits an error: NameError: name 'NSPNGFileType' is not defined" number 1

Answer (score 14):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) gives you a cmdlet that lets extract frames of an animated gif.

This will extract the first 10 frames of the file "animated.gif"

```
# convert 'animated.gif[0-10]' frames%03d.png
```

Comment: is there a way to do so without installing external applications? I am thinking of writing an app where you simply choose a file and once its clicked the frames of the GIF are generated at a specified location

Comment: @user3541125 On animated GIF, sips can convert the first frame only

Answer (score 10):

For anyone interested in the way to export a single frame with the native Preview app...

1. Open the GIF with OS X native Preview app
2. Scroll to the frame you want to extract
3. Click and drag the icon (in the left pane) to your desktop

http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/preview-extracting-frames-from-animated-gifs

Comment: Note that Preview doesn't handle large GIFs i.e., 10+ MB or hundreds of frames well at all.

Comment: You can use Gif Preview available in Mac App Store!

Comment: This would mean that if your GIF contains 100 frames, you are going to have to manually name 100 files, or you will end up with nonsense like "Untitiled-1 (dragged).tiff""